# PYMongo: Keep returning _id in every record after quering, How can I exclude this record?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am having problem when I do a query to mongodb using pymongo.
I do not know how to avoid getting the _id for each record.

I am doing something like this,

result = db.meta.find(filters, [
                                   'model',
                                'fields.parent',
                                'fields.status',
                               'fields.slug',
                               'fields.firm',
                               'fields.properties'])

I do not want to iterate the cursor elements only to delete a field.
Thanks,

Joaquin

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude the id object this way:

```
db.meta.find({}, {"_id" : 0})
```

Comment: Is this because it's looking for an _id of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Does make any sense. The object id is core part of each document. Convert the BSON/JSON document to a native datastructure (depending on your implementation language) and remove _id on this level. Apart from that it does not make much sense what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank for you reply, but I am using mongo for a large amount of data API, I really do not want to share the _id of each record with the world and for performance issues, I do not want to iterate and remove it for the result. I keep the _id for internal process.